# The "ResolveComReference" task is not supported in the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Use MS Build .NET Framework

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a VS Solution with several Projects that when I execute in VS 2022 in Windows 10 all works fine but when I execute in VS for Mac v 17.4.2 I get this error

"/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.101/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Error MSB4803: No se admite la tarea "ResolveComReference" en la versión de MSBuild de .NET Core. Use la versión de MSBuild de .NET Framework. Vea https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803 para obtener más información. (MSB4803) (FysegPlanner.Core)"

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, You can add an answer and accept your own answer. This will help other users who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the COM reference to Interop.SAPbobsCOM that seems to work only in Windows.

I have deleted and now works in OSX too